# How to access object by string variable in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a name as string like

```
var name = "senderId";
```

I can access the object the "oldschool" way like

```
var button = document.getElementById(name);
```

That works. But how can i access the object with that id with JQuery? I tried this:

```
var button = $("#"+name);
var button = $(name);
```

but neither works.

Comment: it works have you included jquery??

Comment: If `document.getElementById(senderId);` works, `$("#"+senderId)` should work as well. Simple. You should share a bit more details and/or use the console/debugger built into your browser to debug your code.

Comment: it will definitely work http://jsfiddle.net/Ry3Lv/13/

Comment: It don't work, as @JamesDonnelly said, he made a mistake in his var names.

Comment: @Superdrac He claimed `document.getElementById(senderId)` works.

Comment: @Superdrac Seems to be one of the cases when OP does not share vital information. Either not included jQuery, or does something between these calls that he thinks is not relevant (maybe only syntax errors).

Comment: @kapa Oh god. That was my mistake. Edited the comment with new link ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is called `name`, not `senderId`:

```
var name = "senderId";
```

Change your selector to:

```
var button = $("#"+name);
```

If that doesn't fix your problem then it sounds like you don't have jQuery included on your page. You can either download it ([from jQuery's own website](http://jquery.com/download/)) and host it locally, including it using:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can instead use a CDN like [Google's](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) by including:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Note that these should be included before your own JavaScript, and should be wrapped within [a `$(document).ready()` function](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).*

Comment: @user3351652 are you sure that your vars are defined in same space ?

Comment: @user3351652 Next time, please AT LEAST read the basic jQuery tutorial before asking questions like this.  Please.

Answer (score 0):

Is this view page is having jsf components?

If JSF components are involved like h:form then you have access by form id then element in jquery